# Selenium Get jsp generated Page Source

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I have a website that populate its content using JSP.

I am trying to use Selenium to scrape the content there. When I opened up the page, I put a time sleep a few seconds and wait until the page fully loaded(I can see the data finished populating by eye-balling).

However, when I do browser.find_elements_by_class... I cannot find any element! I don't know how can I solve that issue in Selenium.

Comment: Check to see if your elements are inside of a frame or iframe.  If they are, you will need to use `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("identifier")` or python equivalent prior to finding the element.

Comment: @Richard what is the identifier?

Comment: The identifier is generally the name or id of the frame.  You can also use a count (from 0) to identify the frame, but I would recommend using name or id of the frame if you can.  You may also be able to use a selector for the frame, I'm not sure if python has Frame(WebElement).

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames documents the python version, which turns out to be `driver.switch_to_frame("framename")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check and see if your elements are inside of a frame or iframe.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames documents the python version, which turns out to be:

```
 driver.switch_to_frame("framename")
```